# 90th percentile is greater than max value. Is it correct?

Tags: jmeter

Conducted web services tests for 2 services.
Test Plan has:
1st service under Once Only controller(login)
2nd service under Loop controller (search)
Both of above controllers are added under transaction controller

Each service has 90% about 300ms.
In Transaction controller for these 2 webservices the 90% is about 2seconds

Is there anything wrong in my test plan? Or Jmeter calculations are incorrect.
I'm using JMeter Version 3.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

90% percentile cannot be higher than the maximum response time, most probably you're getting confused by the transaction controller's output.

[Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) simply sums the response times of its children so it might be the case you're comparing 90% percentile of the Transaction Controller with the maximum response time for the individual sampler.

Also be aware that according to the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or whatever is the latest stable JMeter version available at [JMeter Downloads page](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)) as soon as possible

Comment: @DmitriT- yes the 90% response time of children is lesser than 90% of transaction controller. Also the 90% in transaction controller is about 2 sec where as the 90% of both children samplers are 500 ms. 
IS it good practice to add transaction controllers to webservices? in this case the reading of transaction is misleading.